# Where are the APIs for playing an audio cd on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

How would I go about writing a CD player app for Mac OS X? I can find a DVD playback framework and a CD Authoring framework, but no APIs for playing an audio CD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a [sample program](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioCDSample/Listings/AudioCDSample_c.html) from which you can learn how to do this. Basically, CD-DA tracks are represented by the file system as normal AIFFs. You can use the QuickTime or CoreAudio APIs to play them.